# Установка SQLServer 2014 Express

Tags: sql

Почему при установке SQLServer 2014 Express требуется dotnet 3.5, хотя уже есть dotnet 4?

Comment: Видимо потому, что в том году когда вышел 2014 sqlserver еще не было 4 платформы

Comment: @Mike но тем не менее SQLServer 2012 установился на dotnet 4 без требования установить dotnet 3,5.  хотя при выпуске SQLServer 2012 никакого dotnet 4 еще и в помине не было

Comment: Потому что в 2012 не задействованы функции либы 3,5, а в 2014 задействованы. И если подшита библиотека 3,5 то 4.0 вместо неё майкрософтовский "линкер" не подшивает.

Comment: @nick_n_a а где посмотреть можно конкртно про то какие либы задействованы в  2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что в 2012 не задействованы функции либы 3,5, а в 2014 задействованы.